# Is it possible to test Google Cloud Text-to-Speech voice in Dialogflow Action Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I want to use a WaveNet voice for my Dialogflow agent for Google Assistant instead of the standard robotic TTS voice. So I bumped into this [article](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/text-to-speech#agent_settings_for_speech).

As I understand, it is possible to get an output audio file with the answer of the bot in a WaveNet voice, but it would also be nice if I could hear this voice in the action console of Dialogflow or my Google Home.
Is it possible to hear another voice in the console than the regular TTS voice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSML with Dialogflow to attach your own .ogg files.

Google provides [a sample use case on Github](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-ssml-nodejs/blob/master/functions/responses.js), if you're curious. Code attached:

```
<speak>
  The key element for layered sound mixing is <sub alias="par">${'<par>'}</sub>
  (as in "parallel") which inserts a mixed sound at the current point of the TTS.
  It is similar to the <sub alias="paragraph">${'<p>'}</sub>
  element with an important difference of not displaying
  the text content in chat bubbles on surfaces with displays.
  <par>
    <media xml:id="first_thing" begin="2.5s">
      <speak>
        This media element contains a <sub alias="speak element">${'<speak>'}</sub> for TTS.
        It has an <say-as interpret-as="verbatim">xml:id</say-as> attribute so that other
        <sub alias="media">${'<media>'}</sub> elements can refer to it.
        There is also a "begin" attribute that delays the start time by 2.5 seconds.
        Millisecond units are also supported by the
        <say-as interpret-as="letters">ms</say-as> suffix.
      </speak>
    </media>
    <media xml:id="second_thing" soundLevel="-1dB" repeatCount="3">
      <audio src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/cartoon_boing.ogg">
        The sound source for this <sub alias="audio">${'<audio>'}</sub> element is missing.
        Find more sounds at https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/sound-library.
      </audio>
    </media>
    <media xml:id="last_thing" begin="first_thing.end + 1234ms">
      <speak>
        This TTS starts <say-as interpret-as="units">1234 milliseconds</say-as>
        after the end of the media element with the
        <say-as interpret-as="verbatim">xml:id</say-as> equal to "first_thing".
      </speak>
    </media>
  </par>
</speak>
```

Comment: SSML uses the standard TTS voice, but I would like to use the WaveNet voice